# Can I extend django admin to one of the good looking bootstrap admin templates?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to use django as the platform for a website development. I was using wordpress so far. I liked its CMS and admin system. Can I make a function rich admin backend with django that has; pages, menus, categories, tags, posts, images etc. as the wordpress. In order to make it look good, is it possible to use boostrap or similar dashboard templates? How much of difficulty are you expecting for this project?

Looking forward for your opinions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Django admin is a great utility that comes with django, which helps to create basic CRUD application very quickly.

Now customizing it can be somewhat difficult because it is tightly coupled.

Thought the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin) are awesome and you can see if the customization will get your work done. There are many themes available such as [django-suit](http://djangosuit.com/), [django-jet](https://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) etc. which makes it even more awesome.

You might also want to have a look at [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/en/) and [wagtail](https://wagtail.io/).

Hope it helps!